# Securing External API EndPoint for ASP.NET Web API Service (ASP.NET 4.6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, security, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an external API endpoint that will send email notifications to subscribers. When a subscriberID (50 characters) and a message string is passed to the endpoint, the service will send out a message via email to the subscribers email address. Due to the nature of the service it cannot be locked down by IP address or a certificate file or use OAuth2. A third party will be hitting this endpoint with messages to send out to subscribers.

There are currently 100,000 plus subscribers, what are the odds if a malicious user were to find this endpoint that they could randomly try subscriberIds and find valid ones and start sending them emails given the fact that an ID is 50+ characters long and there are about 100000 valid subscriberIds.

What are my best options for securing this API endpoint? Here are my thoughts so far, either add a api key that only the third party knows and will send on every request and/or generate a token for every subscriber and save it to a database and then on the endpoint require them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution for securing Web API's is using [JWT](https://jwt.io/)
If you are building your Web API using ASP.NET Core, it's much easier to use it, as it is a built-in feature.

Also, do you have some limitations regarding the number of emails a subscriber can send? It may be a good idea to have a threshold for each user (every minute,hourly,daily,etc), so you can avoid been spammed by a malicious user that has access to your Web API.